# Get the file sizes of multiple files from stdin (C)

Tags: c, filenames, stdin

I am trying to read and get the total of filesizes of multiple files from 1 line from stdin. The code below works perfectly if there is 1 file but if there are multiple it fails because it cannot distinguish when 1 file ends and the other begins. The filenames are separated by whitespace (ex: echo "file1.txt file2.txt"), can someone point me in the right direction to how I can evaluate each filename's size individually? The filesize function was not included for the sake of brevity

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char tmpstring[1024];
    const char* fileName;
    off_t size;
    char* pos;
    int total = 0;

    //read from stdin
    while (fgets(tmpstring, 1024, stdin)) 
    {
        fileName = tmpstring;
        if ((pos=strchr(fileName, '\n')) != NULL)
            *pos = '\0';


        printf("this is the name: %s\n", fileName); //#DEBUG
        size = filesize(fileName);
        total += size;
    //} #DEBUG

    }


    printf("This is the total: %d\n", total); //#DEBUG
    return -1;

}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to split a line by white spaces?

Comment: Use `strtok()` to search for either space or newline, instead of using `strchr()` to look only for newlines.

Comment: That is what I thought I would do using strtok, but I was wondering if there was an easier, more elegant way

Comment: BTW, what will you do if you have filenames with space in them?

Comment: Im assuming the filenames do not have spaces in them based on project specs

Comment: There's nothing easier than `strtok()` in standard C for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `scanf` instead:

```
int main() {
    char buffer[1024];
    int total = 0;

    while (scanf("%1023s", buffer) == 1) {
        printf("this is the name: %s\n", buffer);
        total += filesize(buffer);
    }

    printf("This is the total: %d\n", total);
    return 0; // You shouldn't return -1!
}
```

`scanf` first consumes leading whitespace, and then reads a sequence of non-whitespace characters. The return value 1 indicates that a string was successfully read (caveat: `scanf` actually returns the number of input items matched; see the manual!).

The maximum field width specifier (the `1023` in `%1023s`) is necessary to avoid a [buffer overflow vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). Had I omitted it, it would have been possible to feed a string much longer than 1023 characters to `scanf`. The extra character is required to store the null terminator.

Note: A (possibly undesirable) side-effect of this approach is that it's not necessary to enter all the file names on a single line. If you don't want this behavior, a modification of your initial approach does the trick:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char buffer[1024];
    const char* fileName;
    int total = 0;
    char *pos;

    // Read from stdin. You should do some error checking too.
    fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);

    // Get rid of the trailing '\n'.
    if ((pos = strchr(buffer, '\n')) != NULL)
        *pos = '\0';

    fileName = strtok(buffer, " ");
    while (fileName) {
        printf("this is the name: %s\n", fileName);
        total += filesize(fileName);
        fileName = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    printf("This is the total: %d\n", total);
    return 0;
}
```

---

On a side note, **you shouldn't be using `int` to represent file sizes**. It is quite likely that `int` is only 32 bits on your machine, in which case even a few relatively small files could overflow it.